# Unable to get output using multiprocessing in python

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing

I am trying to do feature extraction for my dataset using multiprocessing, each processor for each subject. I have 12 logical processors , and i am using window 10 and jupyter notebook. I am unable to get expected output using multi processing.

*for sake of simplicity here, i have commented the feature extraction functions and just expecting print line as output*

This is what i have done

```
from multiprocessing import Process 
def process(sub):
    #X=fe.fit_transform(subject_1_1[sub])
    #np.save('processed_data/features/subject_1_{}'.format(sub),X)
    print('subject_1_{} is saved'.format(sub))



process_1=(Process(target = process,args = (25, )))
process_1.start()

process_2=(Process(target = process,args = (26, )))
process_2.start()

process_1.join()
process_2.join()

print("Process p1 is alive: {}".format(process_1.is_alive())) 
print("Process p2 is alive: {}".format(process_2.is_alive()))
```

**Output I get is as follows**
Process p1 is alive: False
Process p2 is alive: False

I am expecting this program to output as
subject_1_25 is saved
subject_1_26 is saved

Comment: is working for me !

Comment: are you using window 10 and jupyter notebook?

Comment: no Linux and Pycharm

Comment: any idea how can i make it working on windows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
from multiprocessing import Process


def process(sub):
    #X=fe.fit_transform(subject_1_1[sub])
    #np.save('processed_data/features/subject_1_{}'.format(sub),X)
    print('subject_1_{} is saved'.format(sub))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    process_1= (Process(target = process,args = (25, )))
    process_1.start()

    process_2=(Process(target = process,args = (26, )))
    process_2.start()

    process_1.join()
    process_2.join()

    print("Process p1 is alive: {}".format(process_1.is_alive()))
    print("Process p2 is alive: {}".format(process_2.is_alive()))
```

Comment: @Alfe It would be better if you didn't write a comment, so to just write something. I ran his code and it returned a `RuntimeError` due to `freeze_support()` while it was missing the main process. This change worked for me so I answered.

Comment: There is no limit on how many processes you use in your script but if you use too many your CPU will be overloaded and the processes will be added in a queue to be executed. Although on every process you can have multiple threads running tasks simultaneously, so maybe you should take a look at `threading`